# MySQL Replication master - master

Tags: mysql, master-slave

I have two servers (A & B), with MySQL Enterprise Edition 5.7.21, and RHEL 7.4 version. I want to replicate one table from Server A with a table with different name to Server B. In same time i want another table from Server B to replicate to an another table to Server A, like two master-slave:

masterA -> SlaveB

masterB -> SlaveA

I know how create replication. My Question is if i can replicate one table to another table name. For Example:

ServerA: 
User: myschema
tables: t1, t2

ServerB:
User: myschema
tables: t3, t4

I want to replicate:
myschema.t1 => myschema.t3 (master Server A, Slave Server B) and
myschema.t4 => myschema.t2 (master Server B, Slave Server A)

Is that possible?

I want the result to be the same data in a combination of tables:

--serverA:
select * from t1
union 
select * from t2

is equal to

--ServerB:
select * from t3
union
select * from t4.

Info about my.cnf in both servers, for only one replicate.

ServerA:
**master**

- server-id=1
- log_bin=/storage/mysql/mysql-repl.log
- relay-log=/storage/mysql/mysql-relay-repl.log
- binlog_do_db=test
- replicate-do-db=test binlog-ignore-db=information_schema
- replicate-ignore-db=information_schema auto-increment-increment=2
- auto-increment-offset=1
- bind-address=10.124.xxx.xx

ServerB:
**slave**

- server-id=2
- log_bin=/storage/mysql/mysql-repl.log
- binlog_do_db=test
- replicate-do-db=test
- replicate-do-table=test.t1
- binlog-ignore-db=information_schema
- replicate-ignore-db=information_schema
- auto-increment-increment=2
- auto-increment-offset=2
- bind-address=10.124.xxx.xx

Comment: For what purpose? Would [a `VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) suffice?

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible, you always replicate between tables with the same name because you are replaying the log from one server on it's slave.

Since you seem to be writing to both servers and into different tables, why don't you just have tables t1 and t2 on both and have your application write t1 data to one server and t2 data to the other server and replicate master-master?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Right now I've done it, but I do not know if the application will respond properly.

Comment: We ran a master-master setup at my last job. It worked really well once we had row-based replication running and properly understood the subtle ways in which non-deterministic statements can undermine a replication setup. You should post again when you know how it has worked.